# iOS app rejection issue

Tags: ios, app-store

Apple has rejected my App stating that

> Reasons
>
> 22.2 - Misleading
>
> 22.2
>
> We found that one or more of your submitted In-App Purchase products, and/or its metadata, contains content that could be misleading to users. This does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> It will be appropriate to remove the dot lock password option within the App. This is misleading to users. A screenshot is attached for your reference.

What does this mean. I have put both the dot lock and passcode lock options in my app. The users can switch between the two from settings of my app. I don't know how this could be misleading to users?

This is the screen shot [image]

Comment: can you post the screenshot they said was attached for reference?

Comment: You can ask apple for more information if you think that your app shouldn't be rejected.

Comment: I will definitely do that. The reason they give me doesn't make sense. All i can think of is that they did not understand how to use the app.

Comment: They probably say it's misleading because the UI looks similar to the system one in iOS.  Just change the UI so it has the same functionality but looks different than the default.

Comment: And why someone would down vote my question?

Comment: @MattS. Apple does not have a dot lock control. How can it be similar to their system.

Comment: @MattS. The pass lock on apple has numbers inside the circles.

Comment: Yes, but it looks _similar_, which is probably where apple has a problem with it.  It uses circles and provides similar functionality to one used in iOS.  Without actually providing us with screenshots of exactly what it looks like (the one you provided really doesn't show the whole screen) we can't help you.  You have to remember, Apple is VERY picky with UI's and don't like people copying the look and feel of their products.

Comment: @MattS Apple is pick with UI's similar to theirs because it provides a way for phishing and similar trickery for less technologically capable. For example, on the app Muhammad is talking about, it could provide a way for an app maker to gain the passcode of the device.

Comment: Yep. I figured saying the phishing part would lead to a response like "But I'm not a phisher!" so I decided to go the App store review guidelines section 10.2 route (apps can't look similar to ones bundled with the phone, which the lockscreen would probably fall under), which Apple could've easily also added to their response but chose not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done so I would suggest you to read up on the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/) Like `@Matt` said in the comments, Apple is extremely picky when it comes to UI .
Unlike Android, apple wants you to design your app in a way that the user can use your app like any standard one. In your case a passcode inside of your app could be misleading.
Yes I know how you feel I had few apps rejected for things similar to this.
They must be a different way you can design this.

Comment: This is an update to my existing app. It has been this way for long time. So i don't think its the design issue or the way i have put the passcode inside my app. As i said it was like this in previous versions as well.

Comment: @MuhammadNasir I understand but the approval teams is not always the same, the guidelines could change also (iOS7), it is a design issue from what I can read `remove the dot lock password option within the App`, sometimes they can catch something after initial release. Apple has been very controversial with its approval process, you just have to comply to it.

Comment: Thanks meda for the help. What i don't like about their process is the vagueness of it. They don't explain things properly. They should clearly state that hay this is what is wrong with your app. They write poems for  us.

Comment: @MuhammadNasir exactly they are a pain in the neck, They even removed apps from the apps store after approval smh lol